# Can you use -ne and -like in the same pipe line?

Tags: powershell

I can select a group using `Where-object $_.Account -like "Group_*"`

I can exclude a group using `Where-object $_.Account -ne "Group_Foo_Bar"`

What I'm looking for is a way to exclude something that starts with "Group_*". I have multiple groups starting with "Group_####" and would like to excclude them.

Something like this (I know it's not correct) `Where-object $_.Account -ne ( -like "Group_* )`

Is this possible?

Comment: `-notlike "Group_*"`

Comment: In addition to `-notlike`, if you ever need to negate your operator (i.e. you know how to get all the results you don't want and none that you do, and want a way to switch it) there's `-not`; i.e. `-not ($_.Account -like 'Group_*')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything you're using is a comparison operator and can be used in its place.  You can do `$_.Account -like "Group_*"`, or `$_.Account -contains "Group_5"` or anything of that nature with comparison operators.  So you can simplify what you're doing down to:

```
Where { $_.Account -notlike 'Group_*' }
```

[about_Comparison_Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Comment: **Partly wrong** `-contains` doesn't work with wildcards.

Comment: `-notlike` is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @LotPings Incorrigible does *not* mean bullheaded ;-) It's more a reference to being unreformed than the other meanings

Answer (score 1):

-ne is 'not equal to' that you can define for only single group/mailbox/user.

To use a phrase as `-like`, you can use `-notlike`. So the correct query is:

`where{ $_.Account -notlike "Group_*}`